# Exhortation v. Hortation - difference

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences

Exhortation v. Hortation

Are there any difference in (a) the usage and (b) the meaning of the two?

It seems to me that Hortation is an obsolete word because in OED there is only a very brief information of it.

Thank you.

May I know why do I receive -3 for my question?
is there anything wrong with it?
I want to know because the poor grading prevents me from asking any more question
Please let me know so that I could avoid asking questions that you may "dislike" in the future

Comment: Do you really mean OED (which is not available without paying a subscription), or the brief treatment at ODO?

Comment: The main difference is that the average (US) English speaker won't have the foggiest idea what you're talking about if you say "hortation".

Comment: Great. I'll start using it. My ambition is to speak an obsolete tongue. I just wish I had tried harder with Latin at school.

Comment: @HotLicks You have further reinforced my intention to use it as much as possible.

Comment: @WS2: Although OED doesn't actually *say* it's archaic or obsolete, I think you should take note that their most recent citation is 1721. Do you really want to sound *that* old? :)

Comment: What about *inhortation*?  The OED quote for that is from around 1500.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why do people go to Stratford and watch Shakespeare? Why do they read the AV Bible? I would be delighted to be thought of as an 18th century figure like Dr Samuel Johnson, but I fear the chance would be a fine thing.

Comment: @GEdgar: But OD *does* say that one's both *obsolete* and *rare*. Specifically, ***rare -1***, but I dunno what **-1** means there.

Comment: Ah, Hortation Hears a Who!

Comment: @Fumble I seem to recall that Rare-1 words only got used once. Can't find my magnifying glass though for the 9up version. :) I thought that *hortation* meant putting in a garden, and *exhortation* meant taking it out again. (April Fools)

Comment: You got me why you might get so many downvotes.  I frankly had never heard of "hortation".

Comment: I think if you had quoted directly from The Oxford English Dictionary then perhaps your post might have garnered fewer downvotes. I don't have access to the OED and I would have appreciated a citation. Likewise, looking up words in an online dictionary is something anyone with a computer and an Internet connection can do.

Answer (score 1):

Same meaning.

[Noah Webster](https://books.google.ca/books?id=V_8YAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA502&dq=exhortation%20hortation%20difference&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MVMcVezcAZK_sQTz44HABA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=exhortation%20hortation%20difference&f=false) is telling you "exhortation" is more common.

Comment: During the autumn months, sure, but *hortation* surely prevails during the spring months!